# Arrays don't compare properly

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

The code below is not showing `You Win!`

Can you help me in finding the problem?.
Both of the arrays are strings.

```
Sub checkwin()
    Dim flag As Boolean = False
    For i As Integer = 0 To win.Length - 1
        If mess(i) = win(i) Then
            flag = True
        Else
            flag = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If flag = True Then
        lbl1.Content = "You Win!!"
        Timer.Stop()
        Dim name As String = txtName.Text
        Dim data As String = "insert into puzzleTable([picName], [name], [moves], [time]) values ('mona','" & name & "','" & counter & "','" & x & "')"
        mySql.executeSqlQuery(data)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: please provide the content of 'mess' and 'win' arrays.

Comment: Also you can shorten the code - set flag as true by default and check only if not mess(i) = win(i)

Comment: put a breakpoint on the If and step through the code. You probably have a string padding problem, i.e. one of the strings has trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely string padding with whitespace is your issue (e.g: either mess(i) or win(i) padded with leading/trailing spaces). Please check the string contents in your array or filter it with '`Trim(mess(i)`'

If you're writing a code which only define it as win when all item in mess(i) matches win(i), 
Please use the following code:

**Code #1**

```
    Dim flag As Boolean = True    

    'loop will exit and return flag=FASLE if ANY item in mess(i) not match with win(i)
    For i As Integer = 0 To win.Length - 1
        If trim(mess(i)) <> trim(win(i)) Then 'trim added to filter leading/trailing spaces
            flag = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

If you're trying to write a code to find at least a single matching item in mess(i) with win(i), thus defining it as 'You Win'

Try modifying the 'for loop' code to something below:

**Code #2**

```
    Dim flag As Boolean = False    

    'loop will exit and return flag=TRUE if ANY item in mess(i) matches win(i)
    'else return flag=FALSE if no match was found in all the item in mess(i)
    For i As Integer = 0 To win.Length - 1
        If trim(mess(i)) = trim(win(i)) Then 'trim added to filter leading/trailing spaces
            flag = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reason is that the data in your arrays is not aligned(I cannot say the cause of this, because you have not provided enough information). For a more concise answer provide the content of those arrays.